# I can't parse correct double from JSON

Tags: ios, json, nsjsonserialization

I have a problem with `NSJSONSerialization`.I have a `JSON` object with latitude and longitude values(37.321398 , 28.292399).

```
NSData *l_responseData              = [NSURLConnection sendSynchronousRequest:request returningResponse:&responseCode error:&error];
NSMutableDictionary* l_serverResult = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: l_responseData options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
```

`NSData *l_responseData` has correct number without losing precision in JSON but when i use NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData: l_responseData.... NSMutableDictionary* l_serverResult has latitude and longitude values (double) with losing precision(37.3214 , 28.2924).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can you be so sure that `l_responseData` contains correct data? As far as I know, `JSONObjectWithData:options:error:` does not loose anything while parsing.

Here is a sample code to prove this:

```
NSMutableDictionary *test = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:@{@"Lat": @37.321398, @"Long" : @28.292399}];
NSData *data = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:test options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:nil];

NSDictionary *test1 = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:nil];

NSLog(@"test1 = %@", test1); // This prints correct values.
```

So, I would advise you to check the response that you are getting from server.